# How to set QFont for Qlineedit with password mode

Tags: qt

I am setting Font for my **Qt** Application. The new font changes takes effect for whole application. But I have password field in my application and when change the font, password field shows blank field, even after I enter keys in it. I have set the **QLineedit** echomode as password, but once I change the font using setfont() method, password field shows blank.

Can someone please help me to fix this issue?

```
QApplication::setFont(QFont ("Book"));
```

Comment: Are you sure the font supports the Password character? What happens when you set echoMode to `QLineEdit::PasswordEchoOnEdit` do you see single characters as you enter them?

Comment: What if you use another font face? "Book" doesn't look familiar. Are you sure it exists?

Comment: I tried with different font and problem exists with all the font, Also I tried PasswordEchoOnEdit, but it shows password as text.